# UI not showing up the video stream even though the data stream is received

Tags: reactjs, go, webrtc, rtp

We implemented the code as below so as to broadcast the video received to the server to all peers connected to the server.(Though the code below is not a full implementation and just a initial step where in I am testing if i am able to convert the remote stream received at the server to a local stream). I see that the onTrack listener is getting triggered and was able to see the data but for some reason not able to view the video in the UI.

We earlier implemented similar thing through a direct peer to peer connection without an SFU( Just using React and websockets). That worked well, but when we moved to GoLang and SFU facing this issue. Is there any thing that I need to take care for this change.

Thanks in Advance.

```
peerConnection.OnTrack(func(remoteTrack *webrtc.TrackRemote, receiver *webrtc.RTPReceiver) {
        fmt.Printf("Received a remote track: %s\n", remoteTrack.ID())
        
        localTrackHelper, err := webrtc.NewTrackLocalStaticRTP(remoteTrack.Codec().RTPCodecCapability, remoteTrack.ID(), remoteTrack.StreamID())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        rtpBuf := make([]byte, 1400)
        go func() {
            for {
                i, _, readErr := remoteTrack.Read(rtpBuf)
                if readErr != nil {
                    panic(readErr)
                }

                if _, err = localTrackHelper.Write(rtpBuf[:i]); err != nil && !errors.Is(err, io.ErrClosedPipe) {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }
        }()

        _, err = peerConnection.AddTrack(localTrackHelper)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
}

//This is to send the video stream data back to remote peer

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Below is the media stream info received back by the peer

active: true
id: "MmneRfLzGPkLuPkm"
onactive: null
onaddtrack: null
oninactive: null
onremovetrack: null


// Below is the react code

peerConnection.current.ontrack = async(event) => {
    const [remoteStream] = event.streams;
    setRemoteStream(remoteStream);
}

<ReactPlayer
    height="400px"
    width="400px"
    url={remoteStream}
/>

//I'm able to see the stream data but unable to see the video output in the UI
```

Comment: Is `event.streams` an array or an object? are you trying to restructure the first item of the array?